# Access default file in Java project if JFileChooser is not used

Tags: java, user-interface, jfilechooser

I am working on a simple GUI for a program that allows users to select a properties file to run with. I have a JFileChooser that allows the user to select their properties file. I want to make it so if a file is not chosen with the JFileChooser, a default file found in the root directory of my Project folder will be used instead. This file will then be added to a list< string > to be used with ProcessBuilder in order to run the actual program. This GUI will eventually be exported to a runnable jar file. But, for some reason, I can't add the default file to the list even though it's in the root directory; I should have access to it if it's stored in the root directory. When I print out the file's path, it shows that it is stored in my workspace and can access it but it won't add it into the list< string >.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Here's some of my code:

```
    public void createCommand()
    {
    List<string> commands = new ArrayList<string>()
    commands.add("cmd.exe");
    commands.add("/k");
    command.add("java");
    command.add("-jar");
    commands.add("\"" + filepathtojar + "\\" + "testjar.jar");

    File user_default = new File("user.default.properties");
         //user.default.properties is in the root directory of the project

    String propertypath = getPropertyFilePath();
    if(propertypath.isEmpty()) // nothing is chosen in the JFileChooser
    {
         commands.add("-c");
         System.out.println("default file's path is: " + user_default.getAbsolutePath());
         commands.add(user_default.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    else // if a file is chosen in the JFileChooser
    {
         commands.add("-c");
         commands.add(propertypath);
    }
    ProcessBuilder testprocess = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    ...
    Etc.
    }
```

And my getPropertyFilePath() method is this:

```
   //this method is in another class
   public void getPropertyFilePath()
   {
       //returns the path to the PROPERTIES file chosen in the JFileChooser
       return filechosenfromjfile.getAbsolutePath();
   }
```

When I print out commands, this is what comes out if a properties file isn't chosen with the JFileChooser:

> [cmd.exe, /k, "java, -jar, testjar]

If a properties file is chosen, this is what commands looks like:

> [cmd.exe, /k, "java, -jar, testjar, -c, properties_file"]

I have already tried writing the default file to a temp file and adding that temp file to the list < string > but it didn't work. My current cheat for this is to just allow the users access to that default file and have them choose it in the JFileChooser but I'd rather not have to do that.

Why is it stopping after it adds testjar.jar to the list < string > ?

Comment: What does getPropertyFilePath() return when you assign it to the String propertypath?

Comment: it returns the filepath to the properties file chosen in the JFileChooser

Comment: even when you press cancel? If that's the case, you need to be checking for what int JFileChooser returns. If it's the value for cancel, then you should be returning an empty String rather than the selected file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ignore answer

So if I understand the question, you want it to add `, -c, properties_file` after `testjar` when no properties file is provided?

The code you posted only adds that section if `propertyPath` isn't empty. Simply add the contents of the else to the if statement.

```
if(propertypath.isEmpty()) // nothing is chosen in the JFileChooser
    {
         commands.add("-c");
         System.out.println("default file's path is: " + user_default.getAbsolutePath());
         commands.add(user_default.getAbsolutePath());
         commands.add("-c");
         commands.add(propertypath);
    }
    else // if a file is chosen in the JFileChooser
    {
         commands.add("-c");
         commands.add(propertypath);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Not quite. You're adding two `-c` flags in the first if statement now.

Comment: @Compass Ya, I've reread the question a couple times now and my answer isn't right. Ignore it.

Comment: My main problem is that I can't seem to access the user.default.properties file to add to my list<string> despite it being in my root directory and being able to see the direct file path to it (located in my workspace). After testjar.jar entry, the list < string > abruptly stops and doesn't add in the rest of the entries.